# password protected directory causing 401 errors for flash uploader

Tags: password, apache-2.2, flash

I have quite a basic setup

```
<Directory "/var/www/example.com/public">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Access
    AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/users
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

This works fine except one aspect, i am using uplodify swfupload and it can't upload files because it triggers a 401 error.

Is there any way the uploader can bypass this?

Answer (score 0):

Turn off authentication for the upload folder:

```
<Directory "/path/to/upload/folder">
    ...
    Satisfy Any
</Directory>
```

You can also do it for only one file with `Files` directive.

Another way is the pass session ID to the upload script.

Comment: `AuthType Basic` sends the userid/password with each request. there is no session ID.  You should be able to specify that info in the URL `http://user@password:example.com/public/`